# Pentaho DI Send Mail. Read timed out

Tags: email, pentaho, kettle, socketexception, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to send an email from my Gmail account. Bellow are the SMTP details that I provided.

- Server: smtp.gmail.com
- Port : 465 (also tried 587) Use
- Authentication: Yes
- Authentication User: my full email id
- Authentication password: my password
- Use Secure Authentication: Yes
- Secure Connection Type: SSL

This is the error that I am getting.

> 2016/03/16 17:35:45 - [ftp-poc].Mail - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1
>   from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Problem while sending message:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com, port: 465;  nested exception is:
>     java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I tried these two things.

1. `ping smtp.gmail.com` - Successfull
2. `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` - I get a empty black screen with a cursor
   blinking. No prompt or any text appears when I type. But the cursor
   moves.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail security - you need to authorize access by allowing "less secure" (something like that) access, from the gmail side.

Comment: That is already set up. I once tried with Javamail API. During that time I had to make this setting. But now with PDI, this is the error.