# Pentaho PDI - Mail using gmail account Connection timed out

Tags: pentaho

Whilst trying to send email using GMAIL on the PDI job, I face a connection timed out error.

Settings were as give below

1. SMTP ->smtp.gmail.com
2. Port -> 465 (also tried with 587 and 25)
3. And followed by SSL connection with my full credentials.

This is the error I am getting

```
2016/08/24 11:56:48 - Mail - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Problem while sending message: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I see a similar [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035800/pentaho-di-send-mail-read-timed-out) here but with little help

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using below server configuration i used to send mail from PDI

```
1.SMTP ->smtp.gmail.com
2.Port -> 465 
3. use authentication [check this]
4.authentication user (use your gmail id)
5.authentication password (use your gmail password)
6.use secure authentication
7. secure connection type = SSL
```

when this job will execute in your gmail account a security concern mail will be sent by gmail team and you need to allow that security check

Comment: This is what I tried. You are just reiterating the steps I followed.

Comment: I am able to sent mail by using these steps if you want i can send you mail via PDI using those steps.

Comment: You don't understand, do you? I knew the steps and I knew most of them were successful following these steps. But when I tired they were not working. Read the question again. I am getting an error with exactly the same configuration.